# Qt 5.5 Video shader issue on iOS

Tags: ios, qt, video, multimedia

I'm working with Qt(especially 5.5) on iOS device not simulator
I'm just add Video object to QML code for play HLS stream like below.

```
Video {
    id: livePlayer
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "http://content.jwplatform.com/manifests/vM7nH0Kl.m3u8"
    autoPlay: true
}
```

But Qt returns me bug with log like below

```
Failed to find shader  ":/qtmultimediaquicktools/shaders/rgbvideo.vert"
Failed to find shader ":/qtmultimediaquicktools/shaders/rgbvideo.frag"
QOpenGLShader::link: "ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.\nERROR: Compiled fragment shader was corrupt.\n"
shader compilation failed: 
"ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.\nERROR: Compiled fragment shader was corrupt.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: "ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt.\nERROR: Compiled fragment shader was corrupt.\n"
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( rgbTexture ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( opacity ): shader program is not linked
```

I was doing somethings what I can -Clean, Run QMake, etc-
But its useless.
Give me some help plz.

Thanks have a good day.

Comment: oh I forgot this. when project run, error log display repeatedly. and video is not display. but audio is play. Thanks again

Comment: Which 5.5 build is that exactly? as there is no release yet. You say you're working with the simulator, is it working on an actual iOS device?

Comment: I'm using qt-opensource-mac-x64-android-ios-5.5.0-beta. both simulator and iOS device. actually I posted this for overlay UI of Video in iOS. There is z-order problem in iOS, video view always top of other all QML elements.

Comment: The z-order issue is really weird, it should work (and does for me) as a normal qml item, with overlays, transformations, effects possible on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary bug in the Qt 5.5 branch.

To fix it with the current 5.5 snapshots, add this to your `main()` function:

```
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(qtmultimediaquicktools);
```

The issue is already fixed in the current 5.5 branch of Qt, [find the fix here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/112360/) or wait for the next snapshot.

Comment: I'll test this and be back soon with test result. Thank you for your help.